# How to compare latest value in range with averages based on multiple criteria using formulas in Google Sheets efficiently?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got the following formula giving me the right result, but since it'll be in a couple of a thousand rows, it takes too long to calculate and, sometimes, it doesn't even return the result:

```
=(INDEX($F$2:$F,MATCH(maxifs($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A,$A2),$B$2:$B,0),)>Averageifs($F$2:$F,$B$2:$B,"<="&MAXIFS($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A,A2),$B$2:$B,">="&WORKDAY(MAXIFS($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A,A2),-10)))
```

Here's a copy containing dummy data and the hurdle highlighted, if you could help with any pointers:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sTehnvkjDtZE6PUpXYdiMFKZFwA10EUbzEdszWPDryY/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: Just want to confirm if you plan to retain the formula included in J4, J5, K4, and K5? I'm just wondering if you can just compare those cells rather than combining their formula in a single cell. In addition are you open for custom formula solution?

Comment: Hello @RonM! Formulas in rows 4 and 5 are mostly for clarification purpose. I'm actually looking for an alternative for formulas in row 6, such as sort & sortn, but I'm not aware of how to apply these apparently more efficient functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using [Custom Formula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to process your data with Apps Script.

### Sample Code:

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function compareCloseDateToDays(value) {
  var result = value.flat().filter(String);
  var latest = result[result.length-1];
  var tenDays = result[result.length-11];
  Logger.log(latest);
  Logger.log(tenDays);
  return(latest>tenDays);

}

/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function compareCloseDateToAve(value) {
  var result = value.flat().filter(String);
  var latest = result[result.length-1];
  var tenAve = result.slice(result.length-10);
  var sum = 0;
  var ave = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < tenAve.length; i++) {
    sum += tenAve[i];
  }

  ave = sum/tenAve.length;
  Logger.log(latest);
  Logger.log(ave);
  return(latest>ave);
}
```

### How to use:

- Provide range of close values in the function

```
    =compareCloseDateToDays(F7:F)
    =compareCloseDateToAve(F7:F)
```

### Output:

[image]

[image]

---

### Note:

In your original formula, you include a criteria where column A should match A8 when getting the max value of the date.

You can use [Filter()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to filter column F before calling the custom functions.

### Sample Scenario:

[image]

- I changed A109 to "test"

Then use this function: `=compareCloseDateToDays(filter(F7:F,A7:A=A8))`
The output is "TRUE"

[image]

- Last Value = **14.35**
- Value from 10 workdays = **14.27**

Comment: Un-f'ing-believable! Thanks a million!

Comment: Hi, Ron! If I were to drag it down the column for about 1k rows, that would take a while to load. Would there be a minimum tweak, or the function would really have to be re-written, adding values to an array to be compared and have its result returned and so on? Thank you! That above is really thorough!

Comment: Hi, if you were to extend your data up to 1k rows I believe the function should still run as expected. Notice that we already used F7:F as an input array. The only scenario you may need to re-write or tweak the function is when you want to change your computation formula. Just don't forget that if you have additional criteria needed you need to filter your data first. Please let me know if this clarify your concern or you could provide some sample scenario for me to understand your concern completely. :)

Comment: Hi, Ron! It sure does clarify my question. The challenge boils down to having these 1K rows calculate the output in a timely manner. Thank you very much for the follow-up answer! Cheers.